# hexadecimal to decimal conversion in java

Tags: java

I have a `String` containing hexadecimal number `"dddddddd"` and currently I am using the method `int hex_to_int(String s)` to convert it into `int decimalValue`:

```
    public static int hex_to_int(String s) 
    {
        String digits = "0123456789ABCDEF";
        s = s.toUpperCase();
        int val = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
            char c = s.charAt(i);
            int d = digits.indexOf(c);
            val = 16*val + d;
        }
        return val;
    }
```

when I do `int decimalValue = hex_to_int("dddddddd");` it gives me this decimalValue `-572662307` whereas hexString `"dddddddd"` should be `3722304989` in decimal.
I also tried `int decimalValue = Integer.parseInt("dddddddd",16);` this gave me `NumberFormatException`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`3722304989` is higher than the [max number](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Integer.html#MAX_VALUE) that can be held by an int variable. That's why you get an [integer overflow](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_overflow), and the result becomes negative. That's also the reason why `Integer.parseInt("dddddddd",16)` throws an exception.

If you change your `val` variable and the return type of the method to long, you'll get the expected result.

You can also use `Long.parseLong("dddddddd",16)`.

Comment: Other solution: `new BigDecimal(s, 16).toIntExact()`

Comment: `long unsignedInt = 0xFFFF_FFFFL & hex_to_int(s);`

Comment: i am implementing a cache, and my cache is an **ArrayList** containing int type of Arrays and this value '"dddddddd"' needed to be stored in  one of the index. what should i do now?

Comment: @ShahjahanKhokhar If you must store this number in decimal form, you can't use an int. You'll have to change your ArrayList to hold longs.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try this?

```
System.out.println(Long.parseLong("dddddddd", 16));
```

You get number format exception becouse it's to big value for Integer after conversion, try to remove one "d" and it should work with Integer.parseInt or parse to Long as I showed you above.

Answer (score 1):

Conversion of Hexadecimal value for "dddddddd" is exceeding the range for Integer value range as used in your example. Below code is giving the correct value:

package StackOverflow;

import java.util.*;

public class HexaToDecimal {

```
/**
 * @param args
 */


public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    System.out.print("Provide Hexadecimal Input:");

    Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);

    String inputValue = userInput.nextLine();

    try
    {
        //actual conversion of hex to Decimal

        Long outputDec = Long.parseLong(inputValue,16);
        System.out.print("Decimal Equivalent : " +outputDec);       

    }

    catch(NumberFormatException ne)
    {
        System.out.println("Invalid Input");
    }
    finally
    {
        userInput.close();
    }
}
```

}